# Apply function to multiple lists (Python)

Tags: python, function, class

I want to apply the following function to multiple instances of `a`, `b`, `c` but it seems I can't apply this function to a list. The goal is to compute a few inequalities and finally plug them into a new `z = ax + bx` equation in order to find the lowest or highest ordered pair.

This is a cleaner code that omits the use of lists:

```
xMin,yMin = 0,0
a,b,c = 2,-3,12
enter code here
def FindVar(object):
    x = (-b*yMin)/a + c/a
    y = (-a*xMin)/b + c/b
print '(', FindVar.x, ',', yMin, ')'
print '(', xMin, ',', FindVar.y, ')'
```

This is a longer code that uses lists a bit more sloppily:

```
xMin = 0
yMin = 0

def i1():
    a,b,c = 2,-3,12

    #Create and append l1
    global l1
    l1 = []
    l1.extend((a,b,c))

    #Find X,Y
    y = (-a*xMin)/b + (c/b)
    x = (-b*yMin)/a + c/a

    #Add to list
    pair = []
    pair.append((xMin,y))
    pair.append((x,yMin))

    print '%sx + %sy = %s' % (a,b,c)
    print 'RETURNS'
    print pair[0], z1
    print pair[1], z2

def i2():
    a,b,c = 1,1,5

    #Create and append l2
    global l2
    l2 = []
    l2.extend((a,b,c))

    #Find X,Y
    y = (-a*xMin)/b + c/b
    x = (-b*yMin)/a + c/a

    #Add to list
    pair = []
    pair.append((xMin,y))
    pair.append((x,yMin))

    print '%sx + %sy = %s' % (a,b,c)
    print 'RETURNS'
    print pair[0], z1
    print pair[1], z2
```

So with the second bit of code I end up with 4 list items, each of which should be applied to a final equation, `z = ax + by` where a and b are independent from other functions.

EDIT: The purpose is to take an equation like "z = 2x + 7y" and subject it to the rules: 
2x - 3y ≤ 12, 
x + y ≤ 5, 
3x + 4y ≥ 24,
x ≥ 0, 
y ≥ 0.

I take these equations and put them into a list so that a,b,c = [2,-3,12],[1,1,5],[3,4,24] (where a = 2,1,3, b = -3,1,4, and c = 12,5,24). Then I can find (x,y) according to each of the three instances and plug each of those ordered pairs into my initial "z = 2x + 7y". The point of all of this is to take sets of data and find which set is the most efficient.

z1 and z2 were used in a prior version of the code to apply the "z=2x+7y" to the first and second ordered pairs of the first equation.

EDIT 2:
This is the much cleaner code I came up with.

```
xMin = 0
yMin = 0

a = [10,11,1]
b = [7,-8,1]
c = [200,63,42]

def findxy(a,b,c):
    #Finds x,y for ax+by=c
    x = (-b*yMin)/a + c/a
    y = (-a*xMin)/b + c/b

    #The results, followed by the z function "z = 15x + 15y"
    if x >= xMin:
        print '(%s, %s)' % (x,yMin), 15 * x + 15 * yMin
    if y >= yMin:
        print '(%s, %s)' % (xMin,y), 15 * xMin + 15 * y

map(findxy,a,b,c)
```

Results in

> > > ```
> > > (20, 0) 300
> > > (0, 28) 420
> > > (5, 0) 75
> > > (42, 0) 630
> > > (0, 42) 630
> > > ```

Thanks!

Comment: can you please indent your code? it's very important in python... :)

Comment: Any reason to use globals `i2` could just `return` the list as a result instead of creating it in the global space (same with `i1` and `l1`). This looks like FORTRAN!

Comment: also, where are `z1` and `z2` defined? can you provide a more thorough code that explains what the code should do?

Comment: z1 and z2 were used to apply a new expression, "z = ax + by". This was replaced in the new code by "15 * x + 15 * y"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply a function to each object in a list you can use the built in function [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map).
The list you pass to `map` can consist of primitives, class instances, tuples or lists.

Comment: Wow, this is much more efficient so far. I'll play around with this and see what I can put together. Thanks.